# Platform-Specific Workarounds to C++ Static Destruction / Construction Order Problems

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing with Visual Studio 2008 in standard (unmanaged) C++ under Windows XP Pro SP 3.

I have created a thread-safe wrapper around std::cout. This wrapper object is a drop-in replacement (i.e. same name) for what use to be a macro that was #defined to cout. It is used by a *lot* of code. Its behavior is probably pretty much as you would expect:

1. At construction, it creates a critical section.
2. During calls to operator<<(), it locks the critical section, passes the data to be printed to cout, and finally releases the critical section.
3. At destruction, it destroys the critical section.

This wrapper lives in static storage (it's global). Like all such objects, it constructs before main() starts and it destructs after main() exits.

Using my wrapper in the destructor of another object that also lives in static storage is problematic. Since the construction / destruction order of such objects is indeterminate, I may very well try to lock a critical section that has been destroyed. The symptom I'm seeing is that my program blocks on the lock attempt (though I suppose anything is liable to happen).

As far as ways to deal with this...

1. I could do nothing in the destructor; specifically, I would let the critical section continue to live. The C++ standard guarantees that cout never dies during program execution, and this would be the best possible attempt at making my wrapper behave similarly. Of course, my wrapper would "officially" be dead after its empty destructor runs, but it would probably (I hate that word) be as functional as it was before its destructor ran. On my platform, this does seem to be the case. But oh my gosh is this ugly, non-portable, and liable to future breakage...
2. I hold the critical section (but not the stream reference to cout) in a pimpl. All critical section accesses via the pimpl are preceded by a check for non-nullness of the pimpl. It so happens that I forgot to set the pimpl to 0 after calling delete on it in the destructor. If I were to set this to 0 (which I should do anyway), calls into my wrapper after it destructed would do nothing with the critical section but will still pass data to be printed to cout. On my platform, this also seems to work. Again, ugly...
3. I could tell my teammates to not use my wrapper after main() exits. Unfortunately, the aerodynamics of this would be about the same as that of a tank.

QUESTIONS:

*** Question 1 ***
For case 1, if I leave the critical section undestroyed, there will be a resource leak of a critical section in the OS. Will this leak persist after my program has fully exited? If not, case 1 becomes more viable.

*** Question 2 ***
For cases 1 and 2, does anybody know if *on my particular platform* I can indeed safely continue to use my wrapper after its empty destructor runs? It appears I can, but I want to see if anybody knows anything definitive about how my platform behaves in this case...

*** Question 3 ***
My proposals are obviously imperfect, but I do not see a truly correct solution. Does anybody out there know of a correct solution to this problem?

Side note: Of course, there is a  converse problem that could occur if I try to use my wrapper in the constructor of another object that also lives in static storage. In that case, I may try to lock a critical section that has not yet been created. I would like to use the "construct on first use" idiom to fix this, but that entails a syntactic change of all the code that uses my wrapper. This would require giving up the naturalness of using the << operator. And there's way too much code to change anyway. So, this is not a workable option. I'm not very far into the thought process on this half of the problem, but I will ask one question that might be part of another imperfect way to deal with the problem...

*** Question 4 ***
As I've said, my wrapper lives in static storage (it's global) and it has a pimpl (hormonal problem :) ). I have the impression that the raw bytes of a variable in static storage are set to 0 at load time (unless initialized differently in code). This would mean that my wrapper's pimpl has a value of 0 before construction of my wrapper. Is this correct?

Thank You,
Dave

Comment: You are not the first to have thought of this problem.  There is already a low level lock built into the iostream plumbing.  No point in adding your own.

Comment: I didn't read all this, but it sounds like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck(v=vs.80).aspx) might be useful to you. Basically, you can mess with static initialization order.

Comment: Of course, the C++ standard does not guarantee that cout is thread-safe, but it sounds as if you (Hans) mean to say that Visual C++'s particular implementation of C++ does indeed make cout thread-safe. Do I understand properly?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that I would reconsider what you are doing altogether. You cannot create a thread safe interface by merely adding locking to each one of the operations. Thread safety *must* be designed into the interface. The problem with a drop in replacement as the one you propose is that it will make each single operation thread safe (I think they already are) but that does not avoid unwanted interleaving.

Consider two threads that executed `cout << "Hi" << endl;`, locking each operation does not exclude "HiHi\n\n" as output, and things get much ore complicated with manipulators, where one thread might change the format for the next value to be printed, but another thread might trigger the next write, in which case the two formats will be wrong.

On the particular question that you ask, You can consider using the same approach that the standard library takes with the iostreams:

Instead of creating the objects as globals, create a helper type that performs reference counting on the number of instances of the type. The constructor would check if the object is the first of its type to be created and initialize the thread safe wrapper. The last object to be destroyed would destroy your wrapper. The next piece of the puzzle is creating a global static variable of that type in a header that in turn includes the iostreams header. The last piece of the puzzle is that your users should include your header instead of iostreams.